# Error 0xc000000f when trying to boot Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, bcd

OK, I have 3 entries in my BCD. They are:

1. Windows 10 Insider Preview
2. Windows 10 (Recovery)
3. Windows 10 (ISO)

The 1st one is my primary entry. The 2nd one is ONLY used if the 1st one fails to work (I'm using the 2nd one to post this :D). The 3rd one is to provide a bootable Windows 10 ISO so that I can use it for repairs (Since I don't have much blank DVDs).

The 1st one failed. The error code was 0xc000000f. I think the reason for this is because I ended the Windows 10 setup on Task Manager (I regret this now, no point in lecturing me). There was a new update available on Windows Update (Windows 10 Build 16199) and while it was installing, I ended the process because it was lagging my Minecraft.

Next, I tried the 3rd one to boot into the Windows Setup and then chose "Repair" and then chose "Advanced options" and then chose "System Restore". Once I selected System Restore, the whole thing got SOOO laggy. I waited a whole minute before I lost patience and turned off my PC.

So yeah, there's no hope of fixing my 0xc000000f problem using the 3rd entry. So tell me a way to fix this using the 2nd one... I have Visual Studio 2017 and a lot of UWP apps installed in the 1st one and I really don't want to clean install this :(

Comment: I see a lot on Google about this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+0xc000000f  and it looks like you are on the right track.  Good quality question.  You might want to take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: 0xc000000f = ERROR_INVALID_DRIVE - The system cannot find the drive specified. check the cables of the HDD

Comment: That is NOT the problem in here. I could access my Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare setup just fine, even though it's in the partition of the damaged Windows 10. Plus, how the heck am I to boot into the 2nd entry if the HDD cables are loose?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you have interrupted the recovery/restore process.

Using power off during installation/update/upgrade/recovery/restore is not very good for OS health ;))

1. Fix boot files (using external media like Windows 10 recovery USB). USB's are cheap these days. And writeable many, many times.
2. Fix system files (using offline sfc command again booted from external media).
3. Cross fingers you didn't interrupt Windows while writing system registry files (in such a case only reinstallation can help)
4. Don't rely on Windows recovery or Windows ISO's on hard disk as recovery media (I suppose you use GRUB or some other non-Microsoft boot loader to boot from ISO which means you chainload Windows through BCD=>Windows boot manager and third party boot loader). What if Windows boot manager gets corrupted? How would you fix it?